installed package not showing in ubuntu terminal to remove it ? but if I check version of those package it is showing visible in terminal?
I want to uninstall a package called Knockpy in my ubuntu virtual box. when I'm trying to uninstall it. it is showing like
 sudo apt-get remove knockpy
[sudo] password for david: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'knockpy' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.

but if I go to terminal and check the installed version it's visible there...
david@david:~/Desktop$ knockpy --version
KNOCKPY 7.0.1
david@david:~/Desktop$ 

avid@david:~/Desktop$ knockpy
usage: KNOCKPY [-h] [-d DOMAIN] [-f FILE] [-v] [--dns DNS]
               [--useragent USERAGENT] [--timeout TIMEOUT] [--threads THREADS]
               [--recon] [--bruteforce] [--wordlist WORDLIST] [--wildcard]
               [--json] [--save FOLDER] [--report REPORT]

knockpy v.7.0.1 - Subdomain Scan
https://github.com/guelfoweb/knock

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -d DOMAIN, --domain DOMAIN
                        domain to analyze
  -f FILE, --file FILE  domain list from file path
  -v, --version         show program's version number and exit
  --dns DNS             custom dns
  --useragent USERAGENT
                        custom useragent
  --timeout TIMEOUT     custom timeout
  --threads THREADS     custom threads
  --recon               subdomain reconnaissance
  --bruteforce          subdomain bruteforce
  --wordlist WORDLIST   wordlist file to import
                        --bruteforce option required
  --wildcard            test wildcard and exit
  --json                shows output in json format
  --save FOLDER         folder to save report
  --report REPORT       shows saved report

I installed this knockpy tool through the following commands
git clone https://github.com/guelfoweb/knock.git
cd knock
pipx install git+https://github.com/guelfoweb/knock.git

here again I'm checking whether the package is still visible or not
david@david:~/Desktop$ apt show knockpy
Package: knockpy
Version: 7.0.0-2
Priority: optional
Section: universe/python
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Gianfranco Costamagna <locutusofborg@debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 119 kB
Depends: python3-bs4 (>= 4.12.3), python3-dnspython, python3-openssl, python3-requests, python3-tqdm, python3:any
Homepage: https://github.com/guelfoweb/knock
Download-Size: 35.4 kB
APT-Sources: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 Packages
Description: Python3 tool designed to enumerate subdomains on a target domain
 Knockpy is a Python tool designed to enumerate subdomains on a target domain
 through a wordlist.

david@david:~/Desktop$ pipx uninstall knockpy Nothing to uninstall for knockpy  ⚠️  Note: '/home/david/.local/bin/knockpy' still exists on your system and is on your PATH david@david:~/Desktop$  
someone please look into these issue. what went wrong ?


If you didn't install knockpy by the packaging system (and you didn't), the packaging system won't know about it. Look in the knock directory, for INSTALL*, README* files. Read them.

david@david:~/Desktop$ pipx uninstall knockpy Nothing to uninstall for knockpy  ⚠️  Note: '/home/david/.local/bin/knockpy' still exists on your system and is on your PATH david@david:~/Desktop$  

Run which knockpy to see if there is an executable file for knockpy that is still installed. Run pipx show-app-dir knockpy to display the directory where knockpy is installed. Navigate to that directory using cd and delete the entire directory with rm -rf <directory_name> (in this case knock).
The results of apt policy knockpy will show if knockpy from the universe repository is currently installed on your system.
Results of apt policy knockpy in Ubuntu 24.04:
$ apt policy knockpy
knockpy:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.0.0-2
  Version table:
     7.0.0-2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe i386 Packages

In this case the knockpy package that would be installed by sudo apt install knockpy is not currently installed. apt policy knockpy does not return results for packages that were not installed by apt. For example, it  does not return results for packages that were installed by pipx install

knockpy:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.0.0-2
  Version table:
     7.0.0-2 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 Packages


now tell me what i should do ? how shoud i remove I tried to uninstall it through pipx uninstall

You have already uninstalled knockpy with pipx uninstall knockpy . Installed: (none) reports that the apt package of knockpy is not installed on your system. Therefore everything is normal, and you don't need to take any further action. Try pip uninstall knockpy Try closing the terminal and reopening it. Try logging out and logging back in again.

as you said knockpy uninstalled. I closed my terminal & I logged out and logged in again, this time again I checked the version of knockpy & it's usage commands. the tool continue to keep working again as I was able to check the version of knockpy in my ubuntu terminal and doing recon of subdomains please check below code.

david@david:~/Desktop$ knockpy -d uber.com --recon --bruteforce bruteforce None Recon.....:  83%|███████████████████████████▌     | 5/6 [00:06<00:01,  1.25s/it] 

`david@david:~/Desktop$ knockpy
usage: KNOCKPY [-h] [-d DOMAIN] [-f FILE] [-v] [--dns DNS] [--useragent USERAGENT] [--timeout TIMEOUT] [--threads THREADS] [--recon] [--bruteforce] [--wordlist WORDLIST] [--wildcard]
[--json] [--save FOLDER] [--report REPORT]
knockpy v.7.0.1 - Subdomain Scan
https://github.com/guelfoweb/knock
`

running pipx show-app-dir knockpy showing me piperror   

david@david:~/Desktop$ which knockpy /home/david/.local/bin/knockpy david@david:~/Desktop$ cd david@david:~$  

pipx: error: argument command: invalid choice: 'show-app-dir' (choose from 'install', 'uninject', 'inject', 'upgrade', 'upgrade-all', 'uninstall', 'uninstall-all', 'reinstall', 'reinstall-all', 'list', 'run', 'runpip', 'ensurepath', 'environment', 'completions') 

avid@david:~/Desktop$ cd knock david@david:~/Desktop/knock$ rm -rf david@david:~/Desktop/knock$ ls knock  knockpy.py  LICENSE  README.md  requirements.txt  setup.py  tests david@david:~/Desktop/knock$ rm -rf knock david@david:~/Desktop/knock$ rm -rf <knock> bash: syntax error near unexpected token newline'
david@david:~/Desktop/knock$
`

Hi, karel sucess I was able to completely remove knockpy from system. these time I used  sudo rm -rf knock and I rechecked to see if it is still present in my terminal. finally the file was deleted.

When you use different software package formats (deb, snap, etc.), you must use the appropriate tool for that package format.
apt only works for .deb packages. But you didn't use a .deb package. You used a .git package designed for pip or pipx.
Installing using pipx means removing using pipx
It's generally wise to avoid unfamiliar packaging methods.

david@david:~/Desktop$ pipx remove knockpy usage: pipx [-h] [--quiet] [--verbose] [--version]             {install,uninject,inject,upgrade,upgrade-all,uninstall,uninstall-all,reinstall,reinstall-all,list,run,runpip,ensurepath,environment,completions}             ... pipx: error: argument command: invalid choice: 'remove' (choose from 'install', 'uninject', 'inject', 'upgrade', 'upgrade-all', 'uninstall', 'uninstall-all', 'reinstall', 'reinstall-all', 'list', 'run', 'runpip', 'ensurepath', 'environment', 'completions') how should I reomve/uninstall using pipx ?

david@david:~/Desktop$ pipx uninstall knockpy Nothing to uninstall for knockpy  ⚠️  Note: '/home/david/.local/bin/knockpy' still exists on your system and is on your PATH david@david:~/Desktop$  

Seems like your output includes a lot of important information needed to delete the software. Are you now asking how to delete the file /home/david/.local/bin/knockpy ?

-user535733 yes I want to delete the file or remove it from my directory. tell me how can I do it ?

See man rm for complete instructions using the shell. You could also use the graphical File Manager to simply drag the file into the Trash. NEVER use these methods for apt-created files; doing so will break your system. But you used some weird non-standard git that didn't even meet pipx standards, so rm is safe enough in this corner case. Note that rm requires the complete path to the file...which you have; your output told you the path.
